# How to get first and last occurence of an array of words in text using PHP?

Tags: php, string

```
$arr = array('superman','gossipgirl',...);


$text = 'arbitary stuff here...';
```

What I want to do is find the first/last occurencing index of each word in `$arr` within `$text`,how to do it efficiently in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
<?php
$arr = array('superman','gossipgirl',...);
$text = 'arbitary stuff here...';
$occurence_array = array();


foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $first = strpos($text, $value);
    $last = strrpos($text, $value);
    $occurence_array[$value] = array($first,$last);
}
?>
```

Comment: So there is no built-in function like `strpos` and `strrpos` but takes an array of words for input?

Comment: no, you have to do it like this (or something similar). You could always write a function yourself that can do exactly what you want of course. This is not a very difficult or large pieze of code.

Answer (score 4):

What i think you want is `array_keys` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

```
<?php
$array = array("blue", "red", "green", "blue", "blue");
$keys = array_keys($array, "blue");
print_r($keys);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
)

echo 'First '.$keys[0] will echo the first.
```

You can get the last various ways, one way would be to count the elements and then echo last one e.g.

```
    $count = count($keys);
    echo ' Last '.$keys[$count -1]; # -1 as count will return the number of entries.
```

The above example will output:

```
First 0 Last 4
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want, but additional question, how about if items of this array is another array, then what do you suggest ?

array(
 array(
 "whatISearch" => black
 ),array(
 "whatISearch" => white
 ),array(
 "whatISearch" => black
 ),array(
 "whatISearch" => yellow
 ),array(
 "whatISearch" => white
 )
) 

So I need to find last 'black' position.

Answer (score 1):

`strpos`-based methods will tell you nothing about *words* positions, they only able to find *substrings* of text. Try regular expressions:

```
preg_match_all('~\b(?:' . implode('|', $words) . ')\b~', $text, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$map = array();
foreach($m[0] as $e) $map[$e[0]][] = $e[1];
```

this generates a word-position map like this

```
'word1' => array(pos1, pos2, ...),
'word2' => array(pos1, pos2, ...),
```

Once you've got this, you can easily find first/last positions by using

```
$firstPosOfEachWord = array_map('min', $map);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by using [strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strpos.php) and [strrpos](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strrpos.php) together with a simple `foreach` loop.

Comment: Is there a built-in function like `strpos` and `strrpos` but takes an array of words for input?

Comment: @Runner: None that I know of, but that does not mean much. =)